# View 128 bit TIFF image created by hugin_hdrmerge

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm having trouble viewing a file that is declared to be a TIFF HDR image by [Hugin](http://hugin.sf.net).

- Windows Explorer "Properties => Details" states that the **bit-depth of the image is 128**
- Windows Explorer shows it as a **white image**.
- I've tried converting the image to JPEG via [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org), **white image**.
- Picasa Image Viewer says **"Invalid image"**.
- I've tried opening it in Photoshop CS5, **white image**.

These are the *stiching options* set in Hugin; https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WpLq.png

These is the *Images tab* in Hugin; https://i.stack.imgur.com/LapJn.png

This is the entire output of Hugin; https://i.stack.imgur.com/JILWo.png

Here is the complete TIFF _hdr file; http://c759972.r72.cf0.rackcdn.com/DSC_3873-DSC_3875_hdr.tif **Size: 64 MB**

So, is the problem that I'm not viewing it in the correct mode -- or that it really is a white image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imported your image using Mathematica. After import, it appears white. That is because the pixel values are not scaled properly: The maximum value is 1070 whereas any value greater than 1 is displayed as white. When rescaling the values to run in the range from 0 to 1, one can see the following:

```
In[64]:= image = Import["http://c759972.r72.cf0.rackcdn.com/DSC_3873-DSC_3875_hdr.tif"];

In[65]:= ImageType[image]

Out[65]= "Real32"

In[66]:= Max[ImageData[image]]

Out[66]= 1070.

In[67]:= ImageAdjust[image]
```

[image]

Either the image file is indeed corrupted, or the various programs can't read it. Anyway, the image is not white. There seems also to be some mis-alignment between the poses that were used to create the HDR.

Comment: Thank you, I have observed the misalignment in some of the other outputs as well, I guess I am doing something wrong in the workflow. But you have at provided me with the very useful knowledge that Hugin is actually outputting the image in a format that most other image processing tools cannot read.